# MYSQL count number of answers for a questionn in same table

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

I have a table with questions and answers, the questions have a subject field with the question itself, the answers have a NULL on the subject field. There is a description field that is used as the text in the question and the answer for that question.
Each row has a field that determines if its a question or answer, parent_id field if 0 it means its a question, if let's say 1 it means its a answer.

Example:

```
id | subject              | description          | parent_id
1    How old are you?       Tell us your age.      0
2    (NULL)                 40                     1
3    (NULL)                 30                     1
4    Where are you born?    Tell us the place you  
                            are from.
5    (NULL)                 USA                    4
```

And so on, what i am trying to accomplish is get all the number of replies each question has. My result set would be this

```
 subject              |       replies
 How old are you?             2
 Where are you born           1
```

I tried this but it wouldn't work, any help would be appreciated.

```
 SELECT q.subject, COUNT(q.parent_id) as replies FROM question q WHERE q.parent_id = 0 GROUP BY q.subject
```

Seems like if two questions are the same then I will group them together and increase the replies column value when each one has a separate and different id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query same table twice. One time as questions, another time as answers:

```
select q.id, q.subject, count(1) as replies 
from questions q, questions a 
where q.subject is not null and a.parent_id = q.id 
group by 1.id, 1.subject
```

But the right thing to do is to put questions and answers into separate tables.

Comment: yes this is good, what if I wanted to add joining to another table. Question table has a field called law_firm_id and want to join it with law_firm table. I need the name of a person on law_firm table to add it as a result set field name is name like l.name. Like each question is asked to a lawyer so the result set should also have the lawyer that question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the GROUP BY as this only returns 1 response per parent_id

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a previous reply the best practice would be to have 2 tables - questions and answers.

If you do decide to take this route ...

Table 1 - id (pk), question, description

Table 2 - id (pk), answer, question_id (fk)

```
 SELECT DISTINCT questions.subject, COUNT(answers.question_id) AS replies
 FROM questions, answers
 WHERE answers.question_id = questions.id
 GROUP BY questions.subject
 ORDER BY replies DESC
```

Comment: can't do, its not my database

Comment: Sure thing.  Just thought I would suggest it just in case.  But you have a good answer from Nosyara anyway.  Good Luck